# How can I load website content (link, size)?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm using pig for data preparation, and I faced a problem which seems easy but I can't deal with: Website crawling.

I need to load website content (link, size, page size) on pig, how can I do it? Is that possible?

Comment: wow , TIL pigs are useful. relevant link anyone?

Comment: can write udf to do the crawling